# Reading Video with angular, blob and createObjectURL

Tags: angular, video-streaming, html5-video

I'm trying to read a video. I'm serving my video with a spring boot app using this code :

```
@GetMapping("users/{idUser}/medias/{filename:.+}")
@ResponseBody
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER') and #idUser == principal.user.id")
public ResponseEntity<Resource> serveFile(@PathVariable String filename, @PathVariable Long idUser) throws IOException {

    MimetypesFileTypeMap mimeTypesMap = new MimetypesFileTypeMap();
    Resource file = storageService.loadAsResource(filename, idUser);
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getFilename() + "\"")
            .header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION)
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, mimeTypesMap.getContentType(file.getFile()))
            .body(file);
}
```

and the loadAsResource function from the storage service is :

```
 public Resource loadAsResource(String filename, Long idUser) {
     try {
         Path file = load(filename, idUser);
         Resource resource = new UrlResource(file.toUri());
         if (resource.exists() || resource.isReadable()) {
                return resource;
         }
         else {
                throw new StorageFileNotFoundException(
                        "Could not read file: " + filename);
            }
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new StorageFileNotFoundException("Could not read file: " + filename, e);
    }
}
```

As my spring boot app ask for a token for authentication directly using the path on the server to the src attribute of my video would not work since bearer token would be missing from the request. So I use the following method :

My html is as follow `<sh-secured-video [src]="library.media.path"></sh-secured-video>`

Sh-secured-video is a custom component with the following ts :

```
@Component({
  // tslint:disable-next-line: component-selector
  selector: 'sh-secured-video',
  templateUrl: './secured-video.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./secured-video.component.scss']
})
export class SecuredVideoComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy  {

  @Input() src: string;
  src$ = new BehaviorSubject(this.src);

  dataUrl$ = this.src$.pipe(
    switchMap(url => this.loadVideo(url))
  );

  constructor(private mediaService: MediaService) { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.src$.next(this.src);
  }

  private loadVideo(url: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.mediaService.loadMedia(url);
  }
}
```

The loadMedia function of the mediaService is as follow :

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MediaService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
              private authService: AuthenticateService,
              private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  loadMedia(url: string) {
    return this.http.get(url, { responseType: 'blob'}).pipe(map(e => this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(URL.createObjectURL(e))));
  }
}
```

And the the template for the sh-secured-video is as follow :

```
<div class="video-container">
  <video width="320" height="240" controls>
      <source [attr.src]="dataUrl$ | async" 
              type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
</div>
```

But the video is not playing when using this method. When I use this method to display image it works great but for video it is not playing. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong ? Also I noticed that if I do a video = document.querySelector('video') in the console and then do video.play() I can hear the sound of the video.

Thanks in advance for any response.

Comment: Are you seeing an error on the browser console? Can you see the controls of the video?

Comment: I can see the control yes but there is no error thrown in the console

Comment: Does your problem get when you click on the play button? Isn't that button working?

Comment: When I click on no button I just have a black video screen and when I click on the button nothing is happening

Comment: I think you're returning an incorrect source, I don't know why you need to get your video file in blob type. If you use some mp4 video directly you can see the video playing. Example: `https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4`

Comment: If I put the adress of me video resource into the src url I will end up with a get request which will be rejected by my api since it does not provide the authorization header.

Comment: Have you tried to use a blob video directly without using your API? If you do this, do you get the same behavior?

Comment: In this link, you can see that the video player is playing a blob video https://simpl.info/video/offline/ and you can check the GitHub code.